# Formatting a 'card' in Power BI to show millions to 2 dp, or thousands to 1 dp

Tags: formatting, dax

I have some cards set up that show numbers. I have the formatting set up to "Auto" display unites and Value decimal places set to 2.

The issue I have is when the numbers show in million, that show nicely as $2.28m for example. However, if they're in thousands they show $120.50k as an example.

I'd like to be able to format the cards so if they're showing millions it shows as 2 decimal places, but if the number is int he thousands it shows 1 dp.

Is this possible? I'm very new to Power BI and dax so I'm hoping there i a quick solution.

TIA

Comment: Probably no easy solution. The hard way would be to use the `FORMAT` function inside a `SWITCH` function with multiple cases and specify each different format explicitly.

Comment: You can create a measure using `DAX` and use `FIXED` or `ROUND` functions to round it to the required decimals.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on card
2. Click on format visual right hand side
3. set value decimal places

[image]